# Problem updating state when it is being used in an interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setinterval

I am building a React Native app and am trying to create a timer. The timer runs normally in the foreground using setInterval and updating a bit of state that holds the amount of seconds and decreases it every one second. When the app is backgrounded the date is captured and stored. When the active is made active again I am trying to calculate the difference between the two dates and then updating the state to reflect the difference so it appears to the user that the timer is running in the background.

I am running into an issue where the state is not updated when the timer is running.

```
const home = () => {

  const WORK_SECONDS = 1500; //1500
  const SHORT_REST_SECONDS = 300; //300
  const LONG_REST_SECONDS = 900; //900
  const ACTIVE_COLOR = '#009688';
  const PAUSED_COLOR = '#00695C';
  const ADD_TIME = 60;
  const NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "Time's up!";
  const NOTIFICATION_BODY = "Finished!";

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState({seconds: WORK_SECONDS, timeCap: WORK_SECONDS });
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [timerColor, setTimerColor] = useState(ACTIVE_COLOR);
  const [sessionCycle, setSessionCycle] = useState([]);
  let time = 0;

  const toggle = () => {
    if (sessionCycle.length == 8) setSessionCycle([]);
    setIsActive(!isActive);
    setTimerColor((timerColor == ACTIVE_COLOR && timer.seconds != timer.timeCap) ? PAUSED_COLOR : ACTIVE_COLOR);
  }

  const reset = () => {
    setTimer({...timer, seconds: timer.timeCap});
    setIsActive(false);
  }

    useEffect(() => {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', handleChange);  
        return () => {
          AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleChange);  
        }
      }, []);

      const handleChange = (newState) => {
        if (newState === "active") {
          let resumeTime = moment(new Date());
          let exitTime = moment(time);
          let duration = moment.duration(resumeTime.diff(exitTime, 'seconds'));
          let diff = duration.asSeconds() * 1000;
          console.log("Attempting to substract - " + diff);
          console.log(timer.seconds + " from appstate");
          setTimer({...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - diff})
          console.log(timer.seconds + " after subtraction");
        }
        else if (newState == "background") {
          time = new Date();
        }
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        let interval = null;
        if (isActive) {
          if (timer.seconds == 0) {
            //sendNotification(); 
            // TODO: Add +1 to pomo total after finishing work session
            updateSessionCycle("forward");  
            clearInterval(interval);
            toggle();
          }
          interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(timer.seconds);
            setTimer({...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - 1});
          }, 1000);
        } else if (!isActive && timer.seconds !== 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        } 
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, [isActive, timer.seconds]);

      const addTime = () => {
        if (timer.seconds > timer.timeCap - 60) {
          setTimer({...timer, seconds: timer.timeCap})
        } else {
          setTimer({...timer, seconds: timer.seconds + ADD_TIME});
        }
      }

    return (
        <View style={styles.chart}>
            <ProgressCircle
              percent={ (timer.seconds / timer.timeCap) * 100 }
              radius={Math.ceil(Dimensions.get('window').height / 6)}
              borderWidth={Math.ceil(Dimensions.get('window').height / 30)}
              color={timerColor}
              shadowColor="#212121"
              bgColor="#303030"
            >
              <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', fontSize: 50 }}>{moment("2015-01-01").startOf('day').seconds(timer.seconds).format('m:ss')}</Text>
              <Text style={{ color: '#9E9E9E', fontSize: 20 }}>{(timer.timeCap == WORK_SECONDS) ? "Work Session" : "Break"}</Text>
            </ProgressCircle>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: What is `interval`? I don't see where that is declared.

Comment: You're _setting_ `interval` there, but where is it being declared? Same with `time`; I don't see where your variable is declared.

Comment: Sorry, I moved it temporarily. It is supposed to be declared as this   let interval = null; right under useEffect() Time is declared as global variable as   let time = 0;

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full component all together into one block of code, if possible, including the rendering part in case that's where the problem lies.

Comment: `isActive` is also global? I suspect your problem stems from using global variables instead of state. Still trying to figure out how everything ties together, but maybe you're updating some global variable and nothing is triggering your re-render or effects. Seeing everything together will make this more analyzable.

Comment: isActive is using state. The only reason time isn't is because for some reason I wasn't able to use new Date() using state in the handleChange method. I am working on putting this together. I haven't yet decomposed the file into smaller components yet so it is a bit messy but I will share the key parts.

Comment: I don't see `isActive` in any state in your code as posted.

Comment: Ok, I added the pertinent parts of my code including the View where the time is displayed.

Comment: Much better, thank you. I see you don't ever call `setIsActive`; is that your issue?

Comment: The only time it is called is in two methods which play/pause the timer and rest the timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is you could be using stale state in your call to `setTimer`. In your `useEffect`, you are creating a `setInterval` function that references `timer` in your function closure. Each time that `setInterval` function is called, you'll be getting the same `timer` variable, so the call to:

```js
setTimer({...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - 1});
```

...is going to continuously set `seconds` to 1 second less than the value of `timer.seconds` when you created the interval.

Luckily there's an easy workaround:

```js
setTimer(timer => ({...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - 1}));
```

This will fetch the latest `timer` state each time before performing the update.

Comment: This appears to solve my problem at the moment, thank you! However, I only want this to run when isActive is true. My code never fires if I am checking if isActive is true.

Comment: On further inspection it appears that when I read isActive through console.log() when I enter the app and "active" is true, the value isActive is read as false.

Comment: After further work, I got the function working! I had to add isActive inside my useEffect setting up my event listener.